# PR2 teleoperation in simulation

Tags: ros, pr2-simulator, teleoperation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

Is there a tutorial on how to get the realtime teleoperation controllers (like JTTeleop) working in the gazebo PR2 simulation?  I can't seem to find one and my own attempts haven't worked so far.

Thanks,

Dan

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10253/pr2-teleoperation-in-simulation/) by [Dang](https://answers.ros.org/users/690/dang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 116 on 2011-06-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've figured out what needs to be done, and drafted the tutorial:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_simulator/Tutorials/Teleop%20PR2%20arm%20in%20simulation

---

Originally posted by [Dang](https://answers.ros.org/users/690/dang/) with karma: 116 on 2011-06-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2